# RequestFactory with service layer

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, requestfactory

I need to use GWT with a service-based domain layer - not beans with DAOs. Is the GWT 2.1 architecture with MVP and RequestFactory fitted for this? Or should I stay with RPC?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT 2.1.1 adds a [`Locator`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/shared/Locator.html) and [`ServiceLocator`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/shared/ServiceLocator.html) mechanism to allow you to control how the RequestFactory server code obtains references to entities and service object instances.

For example, you can declare code like

```
class MyService.class {
  // Note that this is not a static method
  public void doSomething() {....};
}

class MyServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {
  public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
    // Or use Guice, Spring, whatever provides instances of MyService
    return new MyService();
  }
}    

interface MyRequestFactory extends RequestFactory {
  @Service(value=MyService.class, locator=MyServiceLocator.class)
  interface ServiceRequest extends RequestContext {
    Request<Void> doSomething();
  }
  ServiceRequest myService();
}
```

If you need even more control over how RequestFactory interacts with your server domain objects or service code, you can inject instances of [`ServiceLayerDecorator`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/server/ServiceLayerDecorator.html) into the service layer.

Comment: Is there any example or scaffold app that demonstrates these features? Thanks

Comment: Thomas Broyer has been a very active user contributing to RequestFactory features and documentation.  He's working on a series of blog posts about RF. http://tbroyer.posterous.com/gwt-211-requestfactory-part-ii  He's also posted quite a bit on the GWT Google Group.

Comment: in which package do I write the MyServiceLocator class? in shared or server? I tried to do that in shared package but it gives an error: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.sample.server.TreeService; did you forget to inherit a required module? This is probably because the shared package shouldn't reference classes from server package.

Comment: If the ServiceLocator implementation is going to be in your server package, you can use the @ServiceName annotation which uses string literals instead of class literals specifically to support the case where the locator or domain objects aren't visible to the GWT module.